# Unclosed Script Tag in AMP CSS boilerplate?

Tags: amp-html

When I unminify the line of AMP CSS boilerplate code, it appears there is a missing `>` closing out the `style` element.

Am I misreading this?

```
<noscript>
    <style
        amp-boilerplate > body {
            -webkit-animation:none;
            -moz-animation:none;
            -ms-animation:none;
            animation:none
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are. It's not a malformed `<style>` start tag followed by a `amp-boilerplate > body` rule, but a well-formed `<style amp-boilerplate>` start tag with a non-standard (given that this is AMP HTML) `amp-boilerplate` attribute followed by a `body` rule.

If you're using a tool to unminify and not doing it by hand, the non-standard attribute might be throwing it off, but then that doesn't explain it leaving the start tag malformed like that...

Comment: Right. Code that serves machines rather than humans, i.e. no `"` to delineate what's what. Clever code.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
<noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate > 
      body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

There is no space between `body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}` line